# Not sure how to parse a string from an array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to parse results from an array that contains strings.

```
myArray = ['thisComp.layer("Body Text")','thisComp.layer("Header")'];

a = myArray[selector];

aRect = a.sourceRectAtTime(5);
```

selector is a slider control that selects items in myArray and it works as expected.

The last line throws up an error - "a.sourceRectAtTime is not a function". I believe I have to parse the result of the second line before using it in the third line but I'm not able to solve this seemingly simple issue.

Comment: Pretty sure the error says more than "is not a function"... Please [edit] your question to format code as code (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You could also use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to help others reproduce the issue.

Comment: Pretty sure the output of `myArray` is `[0] = 'thisComp.layer("Body Text")', [1] = 'thisComp.layer("Header")';`, because you are setting the values of the array as strings. Remove the `'`: `myArray = [ thisComp.layer("Body Text"), thisComp.layer("Header") ];`

Comment: selector IS either a 1 or a 0. Precisely, selector refers to a Slider Expression Control in Adobe After Effects (AE). 

sourceRectAtTime is a built-in Expression method in AE.

The complete error message reads as such - 

a.sourceRectAtTime is not a function

Comment: @RolandKahlenberg Your array, as is, is an array of strings and not an array of objects. Remove the ticks `'`.

Comment: @silentw - I did that initially. However, the result I got when selector was 0 was Body Text and when selector was 1, the result was Head. So, I do need the single quotation to specify the strings in the array. Also, the error was at the second line.

Comment: So now, your 3rd line looks like this when compiled: `'thisComp.layer("Body Text")'.sourceRectAtTime(5);`. As it's obvious, a string doesn't have a `sourceRectAtTime()` method.

Comment: @silentw - My result when selector is 0 is as follows - thisComp.layer("Body Text") 

This is expected and wanted. I think what I need to do is to parse this result into a format that is acceptable to the sourceRectAtTime method.

Answer (score 0):

You've said in the comments that `selector` will be `0`, `1`, that sort of thing.

Your array contains **strings**, but you've said in the comments you want to be able to get the actual thing, not the string.

If you want to use the values as they are *when you create the array*, then as mentioned in the comments, you'd remove the quotes:

```
myArray = [thisComp.layer("Body Text"), thisComp.layer("Header")];
```

That calls `thisComp.layer("Body Text")` and `thisComp.layer("Header")` and stores their return values in the array.

But you've said in the comments that didn't do what you wanted. The only other thing I can think of is that you want to call those functions **later**, when you **use** the array. If so, you have a couple of options:

- If it's always `thisComp.layer(...)`, store just the strings `"Body Text"` and `"Header"` in the array, and then:

  ```
  myArray = ["Body Text", "Header"];
  // ...
  a = thisComp.layer(myArray[selector]);
  aRect = a.sourceRectAtTime(5);
  ```
- If the contents vary more than that, store functions and then call them when you're ready to use them:

  - In ES2015+, you'd probably use arrow functions:

    ```
    myArray = [
        () => thisComp.layer("Body Text"),
        () => thisComp.layer("Header")
    ];
    // ...
    a = myArray[selector]();
    aRect = a.sourceRectAtTime(5);
    ```
  - In ES5, you'd probably use `bind` (but you can do this in ES2015+, too):

    ```
    myArray = [
        thisComp.layer.bind(thisComp, "Body Text"),
        thisComp.layer.bind(thisComp, "Header")
    ];
    // ...
    a = myArray[selector]();
    aRect = a.sourceRectAtTime(5);
    ```

Comment: Thanks TJ! The first option you provided did solve the issue - 

Any idea why it worked? Is it a case of the sourceRectAtTime method expecting either a string or an object? And if this is the case, how would I parse myArray in such a way that my initial code would work as expected?

Comment: @RolandKahlenberg - Glad that helped! *"Is it...the sourceRectAtTime method expecting either a string or an object?"* No, it clearly requires a specific sort of object (presumably a "layer" object returned by the `layer` method), not a string. *"...how would I parse myArray in such a way that my initial code would work as expected?"* You don't parse arrays, you parse strings. But saving code strings and then parsing (well, *evaluating*) them later is an anti-pattern and requires using big hammers like `eval` or `new Function`. Better to do one of the things above if you need to defer the call.